# How to calculate a single checksum for each folder in a directory?

Tags: linux, checksum, file-comparison

I am comparing two large directories between a server and a client machine. I run a command similar to the one below to determine if the two directories are the same or not.

`find /path/to/dir/ -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum | sha1sum`

However, if they are different, I have to descent 1 level to run a similar command for each of the directories and files under the parent directory. While I could write an "for loop", I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to calculate checksums for whole directories, which will make comparison between server/client machine easier.

Note: a single checksum of a folder will reflect the the checksums of the files contained within the directory.

I envision something like this:

```
$ checksumForDir /path/to/dir/*
/path/to/dir/a/  18fad1ea8141fd1
/path/to/dir/b/  17fad1ea8141fd1
/path/to/dir/c/  94fad1ea8141fd1
```

So far, I wrote a one-liner to get a list of checksum from a parent directory... but haven't been able to incorporate the names of the directories.

```
$ ls -d1 /parentDir/*/ | xargs -I {} sh -c 'find "{}" -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum | sha1sum'
29ce013658a00862338ac848c2f90b2e18853a01  -
8f208342084950297b1376f669a9a3c93beca790  -
ae7f589d40f9222d1b06094d0c2f68649fb6cf08  -
```

Comment: the checksum of the list of checksums for all the files within the directory?

Comment: I made some edits to better reflect that.

Comment: You want to compare two large directories? Have you considered `rsync --dry-run`?

Comment: yeah I have... I wanted to have something that will allow me to do a bidirectional comparison between the client and server.

Comment: I can visually compare two sets of checksums between client and server, or use `diff` for large sets of checksums. Rsync will be a bit more blinded imo.

Comment: So if you have files a/x, a/y, b/x and b/y, where b/y is a copy of a/x and b/x is a copy of a/y, the directories are identical (by checksum), even though the names are permuted ?

Comment: yes. I just want to make sure the content is there even if the names of the directories don't match.

Comment: I know the names of the directories won't match. My point is that the names of the individual files may not match, and you won't detect that. So all the content may be there, but you can't identify the actual files. Maybe consider making each filename part of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way I found to do this is with the following command:

```
$ ls -d1 /path/to/dir/*/ | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo -n "{} " && find "{}" -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum | sha1sum'
/path/to/dir/a/  18fad1ea8141fd1 -
/path/to/dir/b/  17fad1ea8141fd1 -
/path/to/dir/c/  94fad1ea8141fd1 -
```

Seems a bit convoluted, but haven't found a better way yet.